# Loading Policies files from https address with flex

Tags: apache-flex, security, flex3, https, cross-domain

I'm having an epic amount of difficulty trying to get a result from a httprequest to a https address.
I'm loading a policy file from the address but I'm still getting the 2048 security error.

I load my policy file like so in my preinitilize handler.

```
private function preint(e:FlexEvent):void
            {
                Security.loadPolicyFile("https://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml");
            }
```

My server gives me back a special token I need and then I try to make a request to the resource I need using a urlrequest and urlloader.

```
private function getprivatetracks():void
        {
                var url:String=new String("https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?oauth_token=" + testapplicationparameters["oauth_token"])
            var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest()
            req.contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            req.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;
            req.url=url;

            var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader()
            loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            loader.dataFormat="text";
            loader.load(req);
            configureListeners(loader);


        }
```

If I trace out the url I'm calling and paste it into a browser I can see the result fine. It's purely a flash thing.
When I run the swf in debug mode from the flex IDE the request works fine. The problem only occurs when the swf is on a server.

I've spend the best part of a day banging my head trying to figure this out.

Could somebody suggest what I might be doing wrong?

I'm guessing I'm lacking some fundamental knowledge about how flash deals with https.

**EDIT 1**

```
Error: Request for resource at https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?oauth_token=0000000NBfKiNXEYG00FWTUGAy5Uw68r by requestor from http://myserver/content/flash/soundcloud/sclive.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?oauth_token=0000000NBfKiNXEYG00FWTUGAy5Uw68r halted - not permitted from http://myserver/content/flash/soundcloud/sclive.swf
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://myserver/content/flash/soundcloud/sclive.swf cannot load data from https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?oauth_token=0000000NBfKiNXEYG00FWTUGAy5Uw68r.
    at sclive/getprivatetracks()[C:\flex_projects\sclive\src\sclive.mxml:74]
    at sclive/authorize_result_handler()[C:\flex_projects\sclive\src\sclive.mxml:62]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at HTTPOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\http\HTTPService.as:763]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:263]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:46]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:74]
    at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/completeHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:409]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

**EDIT 2**

I've tried catching the security error event and checking the url to make sure theres no redirects going on but the handler never gets called! I always get the unhanled exception error even though I've written a handler for it.

Comment: Could you post the entire error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to permit HTTP content to access HTTPS content for security reasons.
So, if soundcloud wants to allow HTTP content to access its data, they should specify it in their crossdomain.xml  (using the attribute secure="false" in the allow-access-from tag).

However, I've just noticed there is also a crossdomain on http :
http://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml

So I suggest you to use this URL instead of the HTTPS and it shloud work

Comment: Well, I haven't checked soundcloud API in details so I can't really say. But it looks like there is a AS3 wrapper for the API :
https://github.com/dorianroy/Soundcloud-AS3-API/wiki

BTW, you don't need to call Security.loadPolicyFile("https://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml");